# Ubuntu Server 16.04 initramfs error after full recovery to new hardware

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, initramfs

I am getting an error after recovering my Ubuntu Server 16.04. It is only booting in advance recovery option (initramfs). Below is the complete error. Can anyone please help?

```
Begin: Running /scripts/local-block...mdadm: CREATE group disk not found
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
  lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
  Volume group "DDNSRV-vg" not found
  Cannot process volume group DDNSRV-vg
done.
done.
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
  - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/mapper/DDNSRV--vg-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

Comment: Please provide more information about your setup. Do you use LVM?

Comment: Yes, I did recovery from my old server to the new hardware.

Comment: How do you migrate the data from the old machine to the new? Have you moved all disks from old machine into the new?

Comment: No, I did it with Acronis Backup Solution. To be honest I am not familiar with Ubuntu Server. Few days back, I got the same error and I did recover it with below command I think but unfortunately, it is not working this time. fsck /dev/sda

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Acronis Backup Solution`, but I think the uuid of the disk had changed. Please update the question. And provide the outputs of `blkid` and `fdisk -l`.

Comment: Sorry for delay. Actually, I am taking it from physical server. Below is the input.

(initramfs) fdisk -l
/bin/sh: fdisk: not found
(initramfs)

Comment: `(initramfs) blkid`
`/dev/sda: TYPE="isw_raid_member"`
`/dev/sdb: TYPE="isw_raid_member" `
`/dev/md126p2: UUID="0676-16F4" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="de9d240f-71ea-487e-8bd5-78f165e231fc" `
`/dev/md126p3: UUID="1b692d98-96c3-4628-8c80-89a0fa781e22" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="a49a8c60-39ed-42f7-ac00-dbbfd4699657"`
`/dev/md1Z6p4: UUID="34bd5a91-3c14-4307-a3c6-3f06100b54cc" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d93c2e7a-8b57-43a0-a594-da48bc39759f"`
`/dev/md126p5: UUID="af7c3c7a-la6f-4271-b8bb-8defOOdde5f3" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="2celf4f0-39c7-4af2-bb19-7f6bbd7fb477"`

Comment: /dev/md126: PTUUID="daccdbf2-8bc6-412b-9fa1-df8cbc431e9b" PTTYPE="gpt"

/dev/md126p1: PARTUUID="336911e4-8ce0-4ccc-acd1-3ccce1b77283"

Comment: Also check output of `cat /proc/cmdlin`.

Comment: boot_IMAGE =/vmlinuz-4.4.0-131-generic.efi.singned root=/dev/mapper/DDNSRV--vg-root ro recovery nomodeset